# Showing only Numeric keypad for ios cordova application

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I am working on a Cordova application. Is there a way we can show a keypad on iOS devices like the image shown below

[image: this]

This can be achieved in Android by setting the input type='number', but in IOS it doesn't work. Need some help!

Adding input type='number' in ios shows a keypad like the image shown below

[image: like this]

Answer (score 3):

You need To specify the pattern Use like this :

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d*"/>
```

Comment: This works for iPhone but in iPad it shows a numeric keypad with all the other miscellaneous keys...like the one in the above image.

Comment: Is there a way we can show a numeric only keypad on iPad?

Comment: do you try like this :
<input type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" >

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work! Do you think it is possible to show a numbers only keypad on iPad?

Comment: I tried in iphone and it work but in ipad i don't know. but i think  when specify the pattern like pattern="[0-9]*" It should work.

Comment: It works with iPad but it shows a numeric keypad with all the other miscellaneous keys(@,#,%,*,") unlike the one shown on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is `decimal` in `inputmode`

```
<input type="number" inputmode="decimal"/>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Comment: Good, but the decimal is made with a comma, not a dot..